# Help me with pixel art grid removal

Tags: pixel-grid

[image: please help this really sucks and i need this image to be without grid]

Help this is really annoying so yeah

Comment: what software you are working with?

Comment: I am working on windows

Comment: Windows isn't 'software' it's an 'operating system'. What software are you using? What research have you done so far? What software have you tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Hahah this is amazing XD

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

1. In GIMP do *Image > Scale Image*. Interpolation: None. Set width to 44px. Or in Photoshop do *Image > Image Size*. Check Resample, set Nearest Neighbour. Set width to 44px
2. Repeat step 1 but this time set width to 880px

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to reverse engineer it, you should just get the original unaltered version, pretty much every sprite from pokemon games can be found online.

It appears to be a menu sprite from generation 3, which can find it here: https://archives.bulbagarden.net/wiki/File:231MS3.png

You can find more like this on other pages of bulbapedia, spritersresource, pokemondb, and many other sites.